# display loading gif on multi-part form submit

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Im trying to display a loading gif before submitting a  multipart-form (file upload), this is my code.. but the image is not displaying.. if i remove the submit() it displays, so.. is not a path or syntax problem.

```
$('#btnSubmit').click(function() {
    document.getElementById('loader').innerHTML = "<img src='<?= url::base() ?>themes/img/loading.gif' border='0' />";
    $('#uploadform').submit();
});
```

Comment: You are not doing any ajax in there. You are directly submitting the form and it should directly take the user to next page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$('#loader').html = "themes/img/loading.gif' border='0' />";

This will insert the loading image properly, although unless you are telling jQuery to submit the form with $.post, then you will be taken to a new submit page so you won't see the image anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the actual builtin form submit method then it is because it starts loading the page long before your gif is loaded I suspect.

I usually use httprequests to dynamically build content so when I submit a new request I change the contents of the page to the loading image until the new page is received.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem was the image request handled by apache.

So i load the image on the div in hide it.

then i show it from javascript:

```
document.getElementById('loader').style.display = "inline";
```

Worked like a charm ;)

Comment: It will show the loading image until connection to the new page is establish in which case it will wipe out the old page and start loading the new one on a blank screen.

If you want a loading image that persists through the entire loading process then you need to use dynamic content loading such as ajax requests.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with Teja's comment. Unless you are doing the submit asynchronously then whether or not the gif display's is really based upon how quickly the browser starts loading the next page (or postbacked page).

What you could do if you really want to show the gif (will have to be ajax of some description though) is...

```
$("#btnSubmit").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // stops any 'immediate' post back or re-direction
    $("#loader").hide()
    .html("<img src='<?= url::base() ?>themes/img/loading.gif' border='0' />")
    .delay(1000).fadeIn(200, function(){
        // submit form using $.ajax or whatever suits - rebuild page on callback or navigate to new page
    });
});
```

Fundamentally speaking though as both Jonas and Teja have alluded to, if you are not doing ajax - then the user feedback is already there (ie the browser's version of a 'loader gif' will display because it's trying to load a new page) - so why bother going round the houses just to get a loader gif on your page and make it look "Web 2.0"?

Either do ajax, or let the browser give the user it's visual feedback.